# How do I get invisible edges on my spackle jobs?

Tags: drywall, spackling-paste

I have a basement that I am looking to eventually paint.  The basement has spackle in various places on the walls, in many cases, way too much spackle appears to be applied, in a rather messy way, with no sanding after the spackling.  I am now attempting the sanding and if need be, some re-spackling of the uneven areas.

I made a mistake in my living room of assuming that if I sand some spackle, even if the edge of the spackling job isn't perfect, it is good enough to paint over.  The result was a wall where I can easily see my poor spackling edges.

How do I fix these areas around the edges of the spackle?  What techniques and tips can I employ?

[image: What I'm trying to fix:]

<sub>Click for full size image</sub>

Answer (score 7):

1. Remove high spots by hand sanding the entire wall with a flat, rigid 1/2-sheet sanding block and 80 grit paper.  It's ok to remove too much, but stop wherever you start to see the sheet rock facing paper or joint tape. Ideally, 100% of the wall will have been sanded.
2. For the areas (if any) where the paper shows before all the ridges (as in your photo) are gone, switch to either a 1/3-sheet or 1/4-sheet flat and rigid sanding block with 100 grit and sand broadly over the areas surrounding the show-throughs.
3. Remove the dust by wiping down the wall with a damp cloth/sponge kept clean by frequent rinsing in a large bucket.
4. Apply a thin coat of spackle using a 10" or larger metal blade. Apply less than required.
5. When dry, shave off any specs etc using the 10" blade over the entire wall.
6. Use a damp 4"x6"x2" sponge to 'sand' the new spackle,  working the sponge from the middle of a patch of spackle outwards towards the edge and beyond.
7. Apply a second thin coat of spackle and repeat the shave/sponge steps.
8. Inspect for flaws using a bright flashlight or trouble-light held against the wall with the room lights turned off.
9. Touch up as necessary.

Comment: +1 for the wide blade and inspecting the area with a flashlight at a sharp angle, two of the more important techniques for me.

Comment: The damp sponge technique for finishing is a HUGE help.  Make sure it's a BIG BIG BIG sponge and very clean and new and only just a little damp.

Comment: Using joint tape compound (light, water soluble, even after it dries) makes for easier sanding and feathering than spackle-type compounds (heavy, hard, non soluble after drying). This is not for significant holes, just joints, edges and feathering.